# Copy a folder and its content to all Nginx vhosts host

Tags: command-line, cp, nginx, recursive

I am interested to know if a single command line that would allow me to recursively copy a folder to all of our NGINX Virtual Host htdocs folders:

I need to copy that folder to all hosts located in vhosts :

```
/var/www/vhosts/*/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect, I don't think the above code/answer is correct.

`if [ -d dir]`  is probably an attempt to  `if [[ -d "$dir" ]]`.. or  `[[ -d "$dir" ]];..`

The following code should work and do what you want.

```
vhostdirs=( ./var/www/vhosts/* )
  for dir in "$vhostdirs"
   do 
     cp -r "folder_to_be_copied" "$dir/htdocs/"
   done
```

Mind also the quotes `" "` around the variables which are essential for the white spaces in directory names to be preserved.

Comment: I attempted to edit the above answer - but yours is the sollution I arrived at - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This script may be helpful:

```
for dir in /var/www/vhosts
do
    if [ -d dir]
    then
        cp -r DIR_TO_COPY $dir/htdocs
    fi
done
```

Comment: this seems quite useful, I shall try this - thanks!

Comment: this change I made solves my problem! thankyou!